# How to set the value in textfield of Struts2+Hibernate program

Tags: hibernate, struts2

I tried Struts2+Hibernate program. It works fine for Add and listing. When i included in Editing a record from list, my process is set the evalue in textfield for edit. I used Dao class for hibernate. so How to do this? 
My edit.jsp program contains following code,

```
 <s:form action="editCustomerAction" > 
    <s:textfield name="name" label="Name" value='<s:property value="customerName"/>'/>
    <s:textarea name="address" label="Address" value="<s:property value="address"/>"     cols="20" rows="4" />
    <s:submit />
  </s:form>
```

CustomerAction.java

```
 public String editCustomer() throws Exception{ 
System.out.println("Edit Id:" +customer.getCustomerId()); 
SessionFactory sessionFactory = 
         (SessionFactory) ServletActionContext.getServletContext()
                 .getAttribute(HibernateListener.KEY_NAME); 
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    customerList = session.createQuery("from Customer where customerId = "+customer.getCustomerId()).list();  
return SUCCESS;
 }
```

I know its pretty simple to others. But please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: question is not clear to me what you want to do and what is your problem??

Comment: As xcoder says, you can't nest JSP tags like that--same as with XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using one struts2 tag within another. Use this :

```
<s:form action="editCustomerAction" > 
    <s:textfield name="name" label="Name" value="%{customerName}"/>
    <s:textarea name="address" label="Address" value="%{address}" cols="20" rows="4" />
    <s:submit />
  </s:form>
```

Comment: Thanks to all. It works fine. Was not clear about my requirement and now corrected, got Output.

Answer (score 0):

On Struts 2.3 works: value="%{#session.customerName}"